# Serialize response with switch on generic type

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, litjson

I'm using **LitJson** and **BestHTTP** libraries on a Unity3D project and I would write my custom *ResponseSerializer* object.
The goal is create a method that uses generics to map the possible response into my wanted object.

So, my first attempt was something similar:

```
public static void SerializeResponse<T>(string error, HTTPResponse response, string insideKey, Action<APIResource<T>> callback)
    where T:new()
{
    var apiResource = new APIResource<T>();

    if (error != null)
    {
        apiResource.error = error;
    }
    else
    {
        apiResource.error = null;
        JsonData jsonData = JsonMapper.ToObject(response.DataAsText);
        apiResource.resource = (T)(jsonData[insideKey]);
    }
    callback(apiResource);
}
```

But in this way I get compiling error on the

```
apiResource.resource = (T)(jsonData[insideKey]);
```

with message:

> Cannot convert type `LitJson.JsonData` to `T`

The possible types of needed **T** are only 4 (at the moment):

- string
- int
- float
- bool

So, I started playing with switch on type but everytime I get compiling error. My last attempt was this (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4478535/2838073) :

```
public static void SerializeResponse<T>(string error, HTTPResponse response, string insideKey, Action<APIResource<T>> callback)
    where T:new()
{
    var apiResource = new APIResource<T>();

    if (error != null)
    {
        apiResource.error = error;
    }
    else
    {
        apiResource.error = null;
        JsonData jsonData = JsonMapper.ToObject(response.DataAsText);

        var @switch = new Dictionary<Type, Action> {
            { typeof(string),   () => { apiResource.resource = (string)jsonData[insideKey]; } },
            { typeof(int),      () => { apiResource.resource = (int)jsonData[insideKey]; } },
            { typeof(float),    () => { apiResource.resource = (float)jsonData[insideKey]; } },
            { typeof(bool),     () => { apiResource.resource = (bool)jsonData[insideKey]; }}
        };

        @switch[typeof(T)]();
    }
    callback(apiResource);
}
```

But the error is always the same:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `mytype` to `T`

What am I doing wrong?
I'm not pratical on C# with generics pattern and I would to learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

As `T` includes both value-types (e.g. `int`) and reference-types (`string`) you need to [box](http://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) the value returned from `jsonData[insideKey]` before by casting to `object`:

```
apiResource.resource = (T)(object)(jsonData[insideKey]);
```

Comment: Hi HimBromBeere, I did as you suggested but when I use **.SerializeResponse<string>(...)** I get the following error:

`The type "string" must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter "T" in the generic type or method...`

Comment: ok, my fault. I defined T as instantiable with newT().
Thank you

Comment: No, I get a crash in runtime during the cast with error:
`Ex [HTTPRequest]: CallCallback - Message: 1: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.   at <0x00000> <unknown method>`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't something like this would be good? I used your first code, but instead of a type-cast, it will create a new json string and will use the generic ToObject to try to create the final object:

```
public static void SerializeResponse<T>(string error, HTTPResponse response, string insideKey, Action<APIResource<T>> callback) where T : new()
{
    var apiResource = new APIResource<T>();

    if (error != null)
    {
        apiResource.error = error;
    }
    else
    {
        apiResource.error = null;
        JsonData jsonData = JsonMapper.ToObject(response.DataAsText);
        apiResource.resource = JsonMapper.ToObject<T>(jsonData[insideKey].ToJson());
    }
    callback(apiResource);
}
```

Unfortunately, it's an additional object->json string->object conversion, thought. But at least it should work.

Comment: I tried your solution but always crashes with the same error