# Error: 'Worker' is a type, which is not valid in the given context."

Tags: c#, types, pattern-matching

I have this code:

```
class SalaryCalculator
{
    List<Worker> workers;

    public void PrintWages()
    {
        foreach (var worker in Workers)
        {
            switch (worker.GetType())
            {
                case Worker: // THIS LINE
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
    // Other code
}
```

The line I commented gives me the error:

> 'Worker' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Why do I get this error? `GetType()` returns a type, doesn't it?

Comment: Be in the habit of providing the exact error or trace message. Probably the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4478464/1531971

Comment: use: `case typeof(Worker):`

Comment: Also the IEnumerable you're iterating has a typo you've put Workers it should be workers, lower case.

Answer (score 3):

In C# 7 the switch statement can be used for pattern matching types:

```
List<Worker> workers;

public void PrintWages()
{
    foreach (var worker in workers)
    {
        switch (worker)
        {
             case Worker w: 
             // w will be of type Worker
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

This makes more sense if the List is of a base type not of the worker type. Also the test for a branch is `worker is Worker` not `worker.GetType() == typeof(Worker)` which has implications with regard to subclasses.