# How to check if an enum is of certain type in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a generic function that receives a parameter type T which is forced to be an struct . I would like to know how do I check if that type of of certain Enum type declared, I'm doing something like this:

```cs
public static string GetSomething<T>() where T : struct
        {
                switch (typeof(T))
                {
                    case Type EnumTypeA when EnumTypeA == typeof(T):
                        Console.WriteLine("is EnumTypeA");
                        break;
                    case Type EnumTypeB when EnumTypeB == typeof(T):
                        Console.WriteLine("is EnumTypeB");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Type type = typeof(T);
                        return new Exception($"Unsupported type {Type.GetTypeCode(type)}");
                }

        }
```

But i'm getting always EnumTypeA even when I send EnumTypeB

This is ideally what I would like to do:

```cs
                switch (typeof(T))
                {
                    case is EnumTypeA
                        Console.WriteLine("is EnumTypeA");
                        break;
                    case is EnumTypeB
                        Console.WriteLine("is EnumTypeB");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Type type = typeof(T);
                        return new Exception($"Unsupported type {Type.GetTypeCode(type)}");
                }
```

Comment: This question [C# switch on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type) seems to be an exact duplicate with different options to solve a problem

Answer (score 6):

Look at this case:

```cs
case Type EnumTypeA when EnumTypeA == typeof(T):
```

That will *always* be true (because you're switching on `typeof(T)`), and it's unrelated to the *type* called `EnumTypeA` at all. It's equivalent to:

```cs
case Type t when t == typeof(T):
```

What you *actually* want is:

```cs
case Type t when t == typeof(EnumTypeA):
```

So something like this:

```cs
switch (typeof(T))
{
    case Type t when t == typeof(EnumTypeA):
        Console.WriteLine("is EnumTypeA");
        break;
    case Type t when t == typeof(EnumTypeB):
        Console.WriteLine("is EnumTypeB");
        break;
    default:
        Type type = typeof(T);
        return new Exception($"Unsupported type {Type.GetTypeCode(type)}");
}
```

Personally I'd *probably* prefer to use if/else for this situation, or possibly a static `Dictionary<Type, Action>`, but it's hard to say without knowing more about the real scenario.

Comment: Thanks that worked I was incorrectly using the case lines, there are more than 2 cases A and B. Actually I have 4, so I think the switch will be better. Not following about the Dictionary option though.

Comment: @love2code: You'd create a `Dictionary<Type, Action>` with a delegate for each type of "what you want to do when presented with that type". The switch statement will definitely work - it just feels a *little* odd to use it matching in the same way each time, just with a different guard clause.

Comment: Yeah, i'm not a fan of this syntax `Type t when t == typeof(EnumTypeB)` , but not completely clear with the Dictionary yet, So with the dictionary i will have the enum type and a call back action, but how I can avoid the switch with that approach ? i will still need to know which is the enum right ?

Comment: Nevermind i see it here in this solution exposed by Pavel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type. Thanks both