# Returning different types from the same method

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have two objects that are similar but not quite the same:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

In both objects `PropertyA` is used for database lookup via a stored procedure, however, the stored procedure used differs between the objects. Assuming the stored procedure returns successfully, the response is used to create the relevant object.

Currently I have two methods that perform the same logic of calling the relevant stored procedure and then creating the object:

```
public ObjectA QueryObjectA(string propertyA)
{
    // shared code

    var result = CallToStoredProcedureA(...);
    var obj = new ObjectA
    {
        // use result here
    };

    return obj;
}

public ObjectB QueryObjectB(string propertyA)
{
    // shared code

    var result = CallToStoredProcedureB(...);
    var obj = new ObjectB
    {
        // use result here
    };

    return obj;
}
```

This works, however, I am maintaining some shared code in multiple places and if I were to add another object in the future I would potentially have a third method (`QueryObjectC`).

Can this, or should this, be improved through the use of generics and if so what might that look like? Perhaps something along the lines of the following?

```
public T QueryObject<T>(string propertyA) where T : new()
{
    // shared code

    // get type of T
    // switch statement that calls the relevant stored procedure and creates the object

    // return object
}
```

Comment: You could extract the shared code. I'd think that's preferable to a generic method that actually only accepts a very narrow set of types.

Comment: Can the calls to the stored proc be abstracted into a common interface? This is do they all have the same signature?

Comment: @CharlesMager That is an option and something I have considered. I understand that `generics` are not always the answer.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain They require the same single argument, `PropertyA`.

Comment: You can return one object of multiple types using an interface, or use a 'Variant' type. But in this case I see little benefit, your proposed refactoring only seem to reduce safety without much reduction in code size when you add everything you need to handle multiple types.

Comment: The generic approach should match best in your case. But doing a `switch` on `typeof(T)` is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type), so, better use a `Dictionary<Type, Func<parameter1Type, parameter2Type, ..., object>>`

Answer (score 1):

So either way, you're probably going to want to create a common interface between A and B. We'll call it `IBase`

Now the simplest solution would be to try move this procedure to inside IBase, and let polymorphism do the hard work for you

```
public T QueryObject<T>() where T: IBase, new() 
{
    var obj = new T();
    var result = obj.DoProcedure(...);
    obj.AssignResults(result); // could be a part of DoProcedure
    return obj;
}
```

with

```
interface IBase
{
    ResultType DoProcedure(...);
}
```

and each A or B would impliment the correct call (possibly using a visitor pattern if needed)

If however this procedure really isn't the responsibility of A or B (from the looks of it it could be, but if it's not) then you can upgrade to the slightly more heavy duty solution of a Factory of some kind.

You'll want a similar interface as before, but this one you can leave empty

```
interface IBase
{ }
```

And a IProcedureExecutor interface (name can be improved

```
interface IProcedureExecutor
{
    ResultType DoProcedure(...);
}
```

The implimemtors would each impliment the function, `ATypeProcExecutor : IProcedureExexutor`, `BTypeProcExecutor : IProcedureExexutor`

Then a Factory

```
class ProcedureExecutorFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, IProcedureExecutor> executors = new
    {
        {typeof(A), new ATypeProcExecutor}, 
        {typeof(B), new BTypePrpcExecutor} 
    }; 

    public static IProcedureExecutor GetExecutor(Type t)
    {
        return executors[t];
    } 
}
```

Then your QueryObject function would be

```
public T QueryObject<T>() where T: IBase, new() 
{
    var executor = ProcedureExecutorFactory.GetExecutor(typeof(T));
    var result = executor.DoProcedure(...);

    var obj = new T();
    obj.AssignResults(result);// could be part of constructor
    return obj;
}
```

The second is probably more SOLID but might well be overkill for your problem.

You mentioned a `switch` statement in your question's sudocode, this is a bad idea. A generic function that switches based on the type of `T` is really loosing all the flexibility benifits gained by using a generic at all.

Wanting to do something different based on the type of an object is really the heart of OOP, so making good use of polymorphism is really the way to go here.

(on my phone so code untested)

Answer (score 0):

By using a common abstract base class `ObjectBase` having the property `PropertyA` you could write

```cs
public T QueryObject<T>(string propertyA) where T : ObjectBase, new()
{
    var result = typeof(T).Name switch {
        nameof(ObjectA) => CallToStoredProcedureA(...),
        nameof(ObjectB) => CallToStoredProcedureB(...),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };
    var obj = new T {
        PropertyA = result
    };

    return obj;
}
```

If the initialization is different for the different object types, then you could consider adding a static factory method to these types.

Objects with factory methods:

```cs
public class ObjectA : ObjectBase
{
    public static ObjectA Create(string storedProcResult) =>
        new() { PropertyA = storedProcResult };
}

public class ObjectB : ObjectBase
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    public static ObjectB Create(string storedProcResult) =>
        new() {
            PropertyA = storedProcResult.Substring(0, 3),
            PropertyB = storedProcResult.Substring(3)
        };
}
```

Generic method using the factory methods:

```cs
public T QueryObject<T>(string propertyA) where T : ObjectBase, new()
{
    ObjectBase obj =  typeof(T).Name switch {
        nameof(ObjectA) => ObjectA.Create(CallToStoredProcedureA(...)),
        nameof(ObjectB) => ObjectB.Create(CallToStoredProcedureB(...)),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };
    return (T)obj;
}
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but this seems to me a bit fragile design. Switching based on strings ..., Knowing all derived classes in the generic method ... Repeating the same logic in all case branches... Maybe it's just me, but it don't see this solution as an improved version of the original code.